# Logout from Twitter using twitter4j library

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, android-twitter

I have integrated twitter into an android application. I have problem in logging out user of twitter account. I have looked at almost all question on SO about it.

All says that twitter does not provide logout function. Few of them states that we can display login page each time using `force_login=true`.

Using twitter4j library I never call twitter URL. Most probably twitter4j handles it. So my question is that how to pass parameter `force_login` using twitter4j library? Is there any way to ask twitter4j library to pass parameters I want?

Answer (score 0):

```
mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(null);
mTwitter.shutdown();  //removed from latest version
```

This works,try, source:
http://wenchaokong.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-twitter-integration-twitter4j.html

Comment: mTwitter.shutdown(); doesnt recognize now